Regular Expression for parentheses
Following on from Highlight characters in cell that are not Latin or numbers, since the codes that I need to examine now have symbols, I needed to upgrade the code.
Problem got fuzzy when I tried to exclude parentheses from being colored red. This is the part I've changed:
If Not (Char Like "[0-9]" Or Char Like "[A-Za-z]" Or Char Like "[/\.,…-]" Or Char Like "[\(]" Or Char Like "[\)]") Then

Code sometimes works fine, sometimes doesn't.
Does anyone know a way to make it work, or maybe a better way to represent Latin chars, numbers and special symbols?

Parentheses do not require special treatment with Like operator. This code should work for you:
Sub NonLatin()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim char As String
    For Each cell In Selection
        s = cell.Value
        For i = 1 To Len(s)
            char = Mid(s, i, 1)
            ' Check if the character is not a number and not a Latin letter
            If char Like "[!0-9A-Za-z()/\.,…-]" Then
                cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' Yellow background for the cell
                cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed ' Red font for non-Latin characters
                cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True ' Bold font for non-Latin characters
            End If
        Next i
    Next cell
End Sub

Exclamation mark excludes characters from the Like list.
Example:


Not sure why, but when I copied the row with Like operator it still got fuzzy and made colored parentheses. But when I copied hole code with different name, it worked. I even went step further and compared the two codes, didn't find any different.
Still, your answer worked as intended, tnx.

Questions should be self-contained as links can go bad.
However, it is relatively easy to test if a character is latin or numeric. Just include the one's you want in the Like [charlist] pattern.
eg:
Option Explicit
Function Number_Latin(s As String)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim vRes As Variant
    
ReDim vRes(1 To Len(s), 1 To 2)

For I = 1 To UBound(vRes)
    vRes(I, 1) = Mid(s, I, 1)
    vRes(I, 2) = Mid(s, I, 1) Like "[A-Za-z0-9]"
Next I

Number_Latin = vRes

End Function


Or, if you need the opposite, just negate the [charlist]: [!A-Za-z0-9]
If you want to highlight all except certain characters, just include them in the negated [charlist].
For Example:
Sub Highlight()
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim ch As String * 1
    Dim I As Long
    
Set rg = Range("A1")
With rg
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Font.Color = vbBlack
    For I = 1 To Len(.Value)
        With .Characters(I, 1)
            If .Text Like "[!A-Za-z0-9()]" Then
                .Font.Color = vbRed
                .Font.Bold = True
            End If
         End With
    Next I
End With
End Sub


Please read MS Help for the VBA Like operator for detailed information on matching special characters. Neither ( nor ) are considered a special character. And these are NOT regular expressions and regex rules do NOT apply.
